# Speech codec that prioritizes complete message over latency?

Tags: audio

I notice Skype and Teamspeak want to send audio as quick as possible at the sacrifice of butchering audio from poor connections. Is there any codec where you just simply send a delayed audio back and forth? Like a TCP audio chat. Does such a service/codec exist? Basically I am looking for audio chat that will be the highest quality specifically for spotty connections by delaying the latency.

Comment: The [help/on-topic] pretty clearly says *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. How could that be phrased more clearly?